# tastypie dehydrate child resource field

Tags: django, json, tastypie

I just discovered tastypie and I think it's awesome. But I'm having some trouble massaging the output of my json.

For example, I have something like this:

```
...

class UserResource(ModelResource):
  class Meta:
    queryset = User.objects.all()


class Video(ModelResource):
  favorites = fields.ManyToManyField(UserResource, 'favorites')

  class Meta:
    queryset = Video.objects.all()

...
```

Where favorites is a list of users who have favorited the video. I want the json outputted to look something like:

```
{
  "objects":
  [{ 
      "title": "video title",
      "favorites": 
      { 
        "count" : 3,
        ["john", "bob", "carol"]

      }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the following?:

```
class Video(ModelResource):
  favorites = fields.ManyToManyField(UserResource, 'favorites', full=True)

  class Meta:
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
```